# Does EcmaScript spec define ambiguous or unambiguous grammar for lexical and syntax analysis

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-6, compiler-construction

A grammar can be ambiguous or unambiguous. Depending on whether the grammar is ambiguous or unambiguous we use different parsing algorithms. I've skimmed through the EcmaScript spec trying to understand whether it defines ambiguous or ambiguous grammar but haven't where they mention that. Can anyone please tell me that?

Comment: An ambiguous grammar with a non-deterministic parser would hardly make sense for a programming language, would it? They don't really need to mention it anywhere.

Comment: May you give an example of ambiguous grammar in a programming language?

Comment: @Bergi, can you please rephrase, I don't understand. It seems that you're saying that the grammar is unambiguous

Comment: @evolutionxbox, see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/ambiguity_in_grammar.htm)

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi Their example grammar `G` is not a programming language.

Comment: @Bergi, so what you're saying that in the real languages the grammar is always unambiguous?

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi Yes, while I have not proven it I'm pretty sure the ECMAScript grammar is unambiguous. You want to be able to use a deterministic parser. They also handle precedence explicitly by their productions, instead of allowing ambiguous derivations with additional precedence rules.

Comment: @Bergi, I see, thanks. Can you maybe post an answer? I'm also very interested in what you mean by _They also handle precedence explicitly by their productions, instead of allowing ambiguous derivations with additional precedence rules._ - a small example would be great!

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi Instead of `X → X+X | X*X | (X) | a` that is ambiguous, ES productions all look like `X → X+Y | Y`; `Y → Y*Z | Z`; `Z → (X) | a` while describing the same language.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, let me think about)

Comment: @Bergi, I now understand what you meant above about precedence :). It's also interesting that ECMA-262 1st edition [was left-recursive](https://dannysu.com/es1-left-recursive-grammar/). Do you know if ES2015 is also left-recursive? Left\Right recursion is used to define associativity so I suspect it's still left-recursive

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com It isn't (the linked article is wrong), the production for `AssignmentExpression` is and always was right-recursive while most of the other productions are left-recursive. We usually don't talk about whole grammars as left- or right-recursive anyway.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, to be honest there's so much conflicting information... If it doesn't contain left-recursive productions/non-terminals, then how is associativity controlled?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com It does contain *both*, that's how different associativities are accomplished.

Comment: @Bergi, confusing again... so the author is right about _some_ productions being left-recursive, correct?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com The author wrote "*This grammar is left recursive*" which I interpreted as "*This grammar is entirely left recursive*" which would be wrong. If he meant "*This grammar contains left recursive productions and is (therefore) not friendly for LL parsers.*", that's correct.

Comment: @Bergi, great, now that's clear. thanks. And judging by [this](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-AdditiveExpression) the new ES edition also contains left-recursive productions, correct?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Yes

Comment: @Bergi, appreciate. I'm wondering whether you yourself have written a compiler? how did you get into compiler theory and ES in particular? curiosity?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Higher education mixed with curiosity, yes :-)

Comment: @Bergi, got it, it's just curiosity for me without higher education :)